# I want to power RP3B+ with gpio but not sure about the circuit

Tags: pi-3, gpio

I got a 4 battery holder (4-Way 18650 Battery Holder from Dfrobot)
And I'm wondering do I need a resistor to power the rasbery pi via gpio 5v pin.
Or do I need something else for this power supply
The idea circuit is
5v-resistor-relay-rasberry pi

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you've not supplied enough information to allow us to help you. Please put some more effort into your question - edit your question so that we have enough information to help you.

Comment: How much more information do you want? Whats there you need to know that you not sure about?

Comment: For future reference, not all pins in the breakout are GPIOs; included in "not a gpio" are the grounds and power pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "power the rasbery(sic) pi via gpio".

It IS possible to power via the 5V & Gnd pins on the expansion header.

You NEED a regulator which supplies 5V ± 0.25V and ideally protected by an ideal diode.

See *Can the Pi be powered through the expansion header?* in [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Putting a resistor in the circuit will cause the voltage to fall below the minimum.

Sourcing a suitable regulator is fraught with challenges - many Pi have been destroyed by unsuitable regulators.

Comment: Thank you buddy I really appreciate your reply. I will just power via USB port since PiS are quite hard to get and I dont want to fry that one, there are ones out there but they are only work on 1amp so probably the pi will be shutting of or displaying low voltage since I will power the monitor of the pi too so my best scenario will be to power through USB for safe keeping